How to use UploadSetToolbarPlaceholder?
How to use UploadSetToolbarPlaceholder to customize the toolbar of UploadSet control? I checked the toolbar aggregation of UploadSet, it has type sap.m.OverflowToolbar and not sap.m.upload.UploadSetToolbarPlaceholder. I tried placing it in toolbar aggregation but it not working.
   const uploadSet = new sap.m.upload.UploadSet("", {
            toolbar: new sap.m.upload.UploadSetToolbarPlaceholder(),
   });

